# AlwaysOn AG Live Migration

Tags: sql-server-2012, availability-groups, buffer-pool, plan-cache

A couple of thoughts on AlwaysOn AG migrations:

Is there a reason why Microsoft didn't implement similar technology to Hyper-V Live Migration to AlwaysOn AGs so that the buffer pool and cache are transferred to the secondary when failing over. I'm sure it's no easy task to keep everything consistent during migration but it would be a great feature.

If I warmed the cache of a read-only secondary before migration would the plans and data in the buffer pool remain once the DB had come online?

I'm only really thinking of migrations between synchronous nodes on these two points.